# Hangfire RecurringJob : For ApiRequest QueryParameters not updated

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, hangfire

Am using Hangfire in my .Net 6.0 project. I have a  recurring job that is called daily and it calls an endpoint with date query parameters. The date parameters are calculated dynamically and they change with each day. They are set for the ApiRequest, QueryParameters properties. When I publish the application, the job is created and it is excecated daily. However, the dates for the query parameters don't change. They stay the same when the application is pushed to the server.
How can this be resolved?

```
var _config = new ApiRequest();
string jobBatch = "Employee list add";
 _config.Endpoint = "employee/add";
    _config.Method = RestSharp.Method.Post;
    _config.ValidResponses = new[] { System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted };
    _config.QueryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"start",DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("M-d-yyyy")},
        {"end",DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy")},
        {"flags","ALL"},
    };
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobBatch , () => ApiJob.Execute(_config), Cron.Daily);
```

Comment: It will help if you show the code you are retrying to run as recurring job, and the way it is registered in Hangfire

Answer (score 1):

Your `ApiRequest` object will be serialized upon `AddorUpdate` call. So your `DateTime.Now` calls will be evaluated at that time, and won't change anymore.

I see no clear way for solving this.
You may for example try inheriting from `ApiRequest` and provide a dedicated subclass which replaces the desired values in the dictionary when the QueryParameters get property is called.

In that case, you will need to serialized with the correct type. This may help :
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/derived-class-not-deserialised-from-backgroundjob-enqueue/1302/2

First declare the a serializer which takes real type into account in Hangfire configuration :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

Then, assuming you make the property `QueryParameter` in `ApiRequest` `virtual` (note : I thought it was better to use `UtcNow`) :

```
public class ApiRequestWithNowAsParameter : ApiRequest
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _queryParameters;

    public override Dictionary<string, string> QueryParameters
    {
        get
        {
            if (_queryParameters == null) return null;
            _queryParameters.Remove("start");
            _queryParameters.Remove("end");
            _queryParameters.Add("start", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1).ToString("M-d-yyyy"));
            _queryParameters.Add("end", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("M-d-yyyy"));
            return _queryParameters;
        }
        set { QueryParameters = value; }
    }
}
```

Then :

```
var _config = new ApiRequestWithNowAsParameter();
string jobBatch = "Employee list add";
 _config.Endpoint = "employee/add";
    _config.Method = RestSharp.Method.Post;
    _config.ValidResponses = new[] { System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted };
    _config.QueryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"flags","ALL"},
    };
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobBatch , () => ApiJob.Execute(_config), Cron.Daily);
```

This is really non optimal but I guess it highlights the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, the link isn't clear what I am supposed to do. Can you please elaborate a little more.